# Open docx content within Eclipse XML editor

Tags: xml, eclipse, ms-word, docx

Given the `docx` format basically just consists of a bunch of zipped `xml` files, I wonder whether it is possible to view / edit it within the Eclipse IDE without manual unzipping and rezipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin provides the wanted feature:

- [Eclipse Zip Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-zip-editor)

Usage:

1. Install plugin via Eclipse Marketplace
2. Right-click on a docx file
3. Choose **Open With** > **Other** and select **ZipEditor**
4. Double-click on `document.xml`
5. Run the formatter via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
6. Edit the content and save
7. On tab close ZipEditor asks about updating the zip file